# Обеспечение реактивности данных во Vue через Vue.set()

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Всем привет. Есть массив с объектами в `data`:

```
data() {
  return {
    products: [
      {
        id: 0,
        count: 1,
        price: 1999
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        count: 1,
        price: 2999
      }
    ]

  }
}
```

Каким образом я могу изменить атрибут `count` у `this.products[0]`, при этом сохранив реактивность? Т.е. у меня есть такой метод:

```
incrementProduct(i) {     
    //инкремент количества добавленного продукта    
    Vue.set(this.products, i, this.products[i].count++);
}
```

Но сейчас это будет менять в `products` объект с индексом `i` на `this.products[i].count++`. Мне же нужно, чтобы это меняло именно атрибут `count`. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Любые данные объявленные в `data` уже реактивны. Если вы мутируете массив или добавляете свойства к объекту — вы ломаете реактивность.

Если вы мутируете элемент массива по индексу и это свойство в объекте существовало изначально (вы не добавляете ничего нового), вы можете спокойно обращаться по индексу и менять это свойство:

```
this.products[i].count += 1;
```

Не нужно использовать [`Vue.set`](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/index.html#Vue-set) (устарело), сейчас есть [`Vue.prototype.$set`](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/index.html#vm-set) Причина этому — объекты в массиве "наблюдаемые" (`observed`). Мутации происходят только в тех случаях, когда вы используете методы `push` и `pop`, либо же добавляете новое свойство к объекту в массиве.